# Get location to save a file without selecting/giving a file in save/open dialog

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I want to save a file with user's choice but there seem a compulsion to give a name in the given field.  But I want that user chooses only  the  location where to save the file.

Is there any another way to do it with or without using the dialogs?

Comment: Suggest a name if you think you can provide a good one, but please don't try to force the user to accept the default name.  The user may have good reason to change it.

Comment: @andrew actually if there are multiple no of files to save in that case i want only location ,, names providing by code.

Comment: I can see your point, but even then you might **base** the name on what the user chooses.  E.G.  You suggest `frame-nnn.jpg` for animated screen capture.  The user instead chooses `anim01.jpg` so the file names become `anim01-nnn.jpg`.  Where `nnn` would represent numbers `001` through `999`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `JFileChooser` allows to only select directories, which you can use to allow the user to choose the location without having to specify the file name. See the [`setFileSelectionMode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSelectionMode%28int%29) method

*Edit*

The following code allows me to just select a directory and hit the OK button

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser(  );
      chooser.setFileSelectionMode( JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY );
      chooser.showSaveDialog( null );
      System.out.println( chooser.getSelectedFile() );
    }
  } );
}
```

You could possible opt to already select a default destination. If the default is good enough for most cases, in most cases the user only has to hit the enter key.

If this is not what you mean I am afraid I did not understand your requirement.

Comment: select directory option don't close the dialog without providing  a name for file .

Comment: i want to close dialog with ok/yes option only .

Comment: select directory option don't close the dialog without providing a name for file

Comment: yes now i understand where i was going wrong ,, i was setting mode after show the dialog ,it didn't strike that time. thank you